# Offline MySQL Table Definition Generator

Tags: mysql, utility, create-table

I'm looking for something similar to the table creation form from phpmyadmin, but it should simply display a CREATE TABLE statement in a textarea below the form.
It should also not require MySQL, PHP, or even a server to work.

I want this for times I'm working on projects and just want to whip up a quick table definition. I'll more than likely always have a text editor open, so being able to save to file isn't a must-have.

I'm on Ubuntu and use Gnome. A tiny GTK application I could stick in my Applications menu would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not *that* hard to get familiar enough with the syntax that knocking out a table definition in a text editor becomes second nature.

However, check out [DBDesigner4](http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/), which is a GPL application which might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the MySQL Workbench:  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.0.html

- Download and install it.
- To see the screen you want, you have to open a connection first under "Open Connection to Start Querying".
- Enter your root password (or other, if your connection is for another user).
- Then your SQL Editor should immediately open.
- From the left column, under 'schemas', open your database,
- then right-click on 'Tables'.
- Select 'Create Table.'